# Update Object $scope item by $parent.$index and $index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

**What Im Attempting to Do**

Im pushing an object into an array, this works as expected. But as I try to update one of the objects in the array via their $parent.$index and $index all objects are updated.

**Object Being Pushed Into Array (Multiple Times)**

```
// Array for Objects
$scope.arr = []
// Object to be pushed into Array
$scope.obj = {
   content:[
      {
         type:"text",
         data:"This is Dummy Text",
         style:{
           "height":"500px"
         }
      },
      // Could be more than one Object within Content
   ]
}
```

The above object will be pushed into $scope.arr multiple times, within the view the objects are looped.

```
// Looped Arrays
<div ng-repeat="l1 in arr track by $index">
  <div ng-repeat="l2 in l1.content" ng-style="l1.style">{{l1.data}}</div>
</div>
```

**Updating by $parent.$index and $index**

So at this point I have pushed the $scope.obj multiple times into $scope.arr and this is where the issue occurs.

I need to update only one of the $scope.obj's in the $scope.arr via a line of the code like the following:

```
// Set $index's to target the specific array items
var parentIndex = 0
var index = 0
$scope.arr[parentIndex].content[index].style['height']
```

An example of a possible update would be the following:

```
var o = parseInt($scope.arr[parentIndex].content[index].style['height'])
var n = o + 1
$scope.arr[parentIndex].content[index].style['height'] = new + 'px'
```

At the moment the above will update all inserted/pushed objects in $scope.arr despite setting the correct $parent.$index and $index. Where as I need to target and update one, not all.

I must be missing something here, any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please re-read your question, and correct it? You refer to objects and arrays, but it looks like either you mixed some things or you think about them not in the conventional way. {} is an object, [] is an array. It doesn't matter how you call the variable (though it helps when you call them consistantly)

Comment: "new" is a reserver keyword n javascript, you can't use it for your variable name.

Comment: @Gavriel I just corrected it. The variable "new" was just used as an example, but thats good to know.

Comment: You're making a mess with parents, that's not a good practice. Use in the first ng-repeat ng-init="myNameIndex = $index" and you avoid to use parent

Comment: @Serginho I have taken note of this, thank you. But the doesn't help with the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pushing, try to do a copy of the object like so:

```
$scope.arr.push(angular.copy($scope.obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you keep the important parts of your code secret (how you insert the "objects" into the "array") I can only guess, that you're "inserting" the same object to multiple places (means: you keep the reference to the same object in multiple indexes in the array, so basically you have only 1 object) and then when you change the object in "1 place" using array[1].object.a=2, then you'll see the change in "each" index: array[4].object.a==2, because they refer to the same object actually